# android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@739b5ae is not valid

Tags: java, android

I am calling another activity from main activity for download quotes in background. It's working fine sometimes, but if the user presses back button and leaves application, then tries to open the application again, sometimes the application crashes with the error below.

I have added logcat of error as well my class which I am calling from main activity. Whats is wrong in my code that crashes the app?

The class that I am calling from Main Activity

```
private class CheckUpdates extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            Log.d("DESOLF", "dismiss loading dialog");
            if (json != null) {
                if (jsonResultNull.equals("true")) {

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            context);
                    builder.setTitle("Check Updates");
                    builder.setMessage("There are not any updates!");

                    builder.setNeutralButton("OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {

                                }

                            });
                    if(SettingsActivity.tocheck==1){
                    builder.show();
                    }

                } else if(SettingsActivity.tocheck==1) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            context);
                    builder.setTitle("New Data Available");
                    String messageTxt = "";
                    if (authors.length() != 0 && quotes.length() != 0) {
                        messageTxt = String.valueOf(authors.length())
                                + " Categories and "
                                + String.valueOf(quotes.length()) + " Quotes";
                    } else if (authors.length() != 0 && quotes.length() == 0) {
                        messageTxt = String.valueOf(authors.length())
                                + " Categories";
                    } else if (authors.length() == 0 && quotes.length() != 0) {
                        messageTxt = String.valueOf(quotes.length())
                                + " Status";
                    }
                    builder.setMessage("There are new " + messageTxt
                            + " Arrived. Download?");

                    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {




                                    Log.d("DESOLF", "start updates service");
                                    Intent getUpdates = new Intent(context,
                                            GetUpdatesService.class);
                                    jsonString = json.toString();
                                    //getUpdates.putExtra("json", json.toString());
                                    context.startService(getUpdates);


                                }


                            });


                    builder.setNegativeButton("No",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {

                                }

                            });

                    builder.show();
                }
                else if(SettingsActivity.tocheck==0)
                {
                    Log.d("DESOLF", "start updates service");
                    Intent getUpdates = new Intent(context,
                            GetUpdatesService.class);
                    jsonString = json.toString();
                    //getUpdates.putExtra("json", json.toString());
                    context.startService(getUpdates);
                }
            } else {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setTitle("Internet Connection Error");
                builder.setMessage("Please connect to an internet connection!");

                builder.setNeutralButton("OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                            }

                        });
                builder.show();
            }

        }

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.d("DESOLF", "show loading dialog");
            mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Please Wait",
                    "Downloading New Status...");
            mProgressDialog.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode,
                        KeyEvent event) {
                    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
                            && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP)
                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    return false;
                }
            });         
        }
```

My error logcat:

```
05-05 11:03:33.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19379): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-05 11:03:33.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19379): Process: com.example.app, PID: 19379
05-05 11:03:33.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19379): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@739b5ae is not valid; is your activity running?
05-05 11:03:33.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19379):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:574)
05-05 11:03:33.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19379):    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:282)
05-05 11:03:33.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19379):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
05-05 11:03:33.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19379):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
05-05 11:03:33.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19379):    at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:993)
05-05 11:03:33.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19379):    at com.example.app.UpdateClass$CheckUpdates.onPostExecute(UpdateClass.java:207)
05-05 11:03:33.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19379):    at com.example.app.UpdateClass$CheckUpdates.onPostExecute(UpdateClass.java:1)
05-05 11:03:33.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19379):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
05-05 11:03:33.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19379):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
05-05 11:03:33.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19379):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
05-05 11:03:33.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19379):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-05 11:03:33.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19379):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
05-05 11:03:33.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19379):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5930)
05-05 11:03:33.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19379):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-05 11:03:33.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19379):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
05-05 11:03:33.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19379):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
05-05 11:03:33.856: E/AndroidRuntime(19379):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

The whole class

```
package com.example.app;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnKeyListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.app.R;

public class UpdateClass {

    public Context context;

    Button zain;

    String siteUrl, updatesUrl;

    DAO db;
    Cursor c;

    String auPictureDir;

    int lastAuthor, lastQuote;

    JSONArray authors = null;
    JSONArray quotes = null;

    JSONObject json;
    static String jsonString;
    String jsonResultNull = "";

    private ConnectionDetector cd;
    Boolean isSDPresent = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState()
            .equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);

    // ==============================================================================

    public UpdateClass(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

        db = new DAO(context);
        db.open();

        lastAuthor = db.getLastAuthor();
        lastQuote = db.getLastQuote();

        siteUrl = context.getResources().getString(R.string.siteUrl);
        updatesUrl = siteUrl + "site/get_updates/" + String.valueOf(lastAuthor)
                + "/" + String.valueOf(lastQuote);

        auPictureDir = siteUrl + "global/uploads/levels/";

    }

    // ==============================================================================

    public void handleUpdates() {

        // check first for internet
        cd = new ConnectionDetector(context);

        if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
            // Internet Connection is not present

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setTitle("Internet Connection Error");
            builder.setMessage("Please connect to an internet connection!");

            builder.setNeutralButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        }

                    });

            builder.show();

        } else {
            new CheckUpdates().execute(new String[] { updatesUrl });
        }

    }

    public static String getJsonString(){
        return jsonString;
    }

    private class CheckUpdates extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            Log.d("DESOLF", "dismiss loading dialog");
            if (json != null) {
                if (jsonResultNull.equals("true")) {

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            context);
                    builder.setTitle("Check Updates");
                    builder.setMessage("There are not any updates!");

                    builder.setNeutralButton("OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {

                                }

                            });
                    if(SettingsActivity.tocheck==1){
                    builder.show();
                    }

                } else if(SettingsActivity.tocheck==1) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            context);
                    builder.setTitle("New Data Available");
                    String messageTxt = "";
                    if (authors.length() != 0 && quotes.length() != 0) {
                        messageTxt = String.valueOf(authors.length())
                                + " Categories and "
                                + String.valueOf(quotes.length()) + " Quotes";
                    } else if (authors.length() != 0 && quotes.length() == 0) {
                        messageTxt = String.valueOf(authors.length())
                                + " Categories";
                    } else if (authors.length() == 0 && quotes.length() != 0) {
                        messageTxt = String.valueOf(quotes.length())
                                + " Status";
                    }
                    builder.setMessage("There are new " + messageTxt
                            + " Arrived. Download?");

                    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {




                                    Log.d("DESOLF", "start updates service");
                                    Intent getUpdates = new Intent(context,
                                            GetUpdatesService.class);
                                    jsonString = json.toString();
                                    //getUpdates.putExtra("json", json.toString());
                                    context.startService(getUpdates);


                                }


                            });


                    builder.setNegativeButton("No",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {

                                }

                            });

                    builder.show();

                }
                else if(SettingsActivity.tocheck==0)
                {
                    Log.d("DESOLF", "start updates service");
                    Intent getUpdates = new Intent(context,
                            GetUpdatesService.class);
                    jsonString = json.toString();
                    //getUpdates.putExtra("json", json.toString());
                    context.startService(getUpdates);
                }
            } else {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setTitle("Internet Connection Error");
                builder.setMessage("Please connect to an internet connection!");

                builder.setNeutralButton("OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                            }

                        });
                if(!CheckUpdates.isFinishing()){
                builder.show();
                }

            }

        }

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.d("DESOLF", "show loading dialog");
            mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Please Wait",
                    "Downloading New Status...");
            mProgressDialog.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode,
                        KeyEvent event) {
                    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
                            && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP)
                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    return false;
                }
            });         
        }

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

            // Creating JSON Parser instance
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // getting JSON string from URL
            // Log.e("url", params[0]);
            Log.d("DESOLF", "url : params[0]");
            json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(params[0]);
            Log.d("DESOLF", "json string has been downloaded");

            try {
                if (json != null) {
                    authors = json.getJSONArray("authors");
                    quotes = json.getJSONArray("quotes");

                    // Log.e("quotes", String.valueOf(quotes.length()));
                    if (authors.length() == 0 && quotes.length() == 0) {
                        jsonResultNull = "true";
                    }
                } else {
                    jsonResultNull = "true";
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wherever you are adding builder.show(), please put the condition whether the activity is finished or not.

Change your context reference to Activity in UpdateClass Constructor:

```
public UpdateClass(Activity context) {
    //this.context also should be Activity, so please make it as a Activity Reference
    this.context = context;

    db = new DAO(context);
    db.open();

    lastAuthor = db.getLastAuthor();
    lastQuote = db.getLastQuote();

    siteUrl = context.getResources().getString(R.string.siteUrl);
    updatesUrl = siteUrl + "site/get_updates/" + String.valueOf(lastAuthor)
            + "/" + String.valueOf(lastQuote);

    auPictureDir = siteUrl + "global/uploads/levels/";

}
```

Like:

```
if(!context.isFinishing()){ //here activity means your activity class

  builder.show();
}
```

Comment: hi ! sorry I am little new in developing and studying. can you please tell me in above my code which is activity I should use in !activity.isFinishing() ?

Comment: Is your asyncTask declared inside the activity class..??

Comment: sorry again...I am still confused with your question. can I paste my activity code which I am calling from Main Activity ?

Comment: Hi ! I have changed code as per your instruction but on if(!activity.isFinishing()){ ....I am getting error like activity cannot be resolved

Comment: sorry..I forgot to change activity name to context. Now check it and You have to change your single line of code i.e., build.show() with the given 3 lines of code which is added in my answer.

Comment: Now error like this "The method isFinishing() is undefined for the type Context" :)

Comment: did you change global context reference to Activity...?

Comment: yes as you have told like this " public UpdateClass(Activity context) { "

Comment: Not only here...Before your constructor , you declared on more Context context right..?? Change that line to Activity context.  i.e., public Context context; into public Activity context;

Comment: Hi ! Thanks...its working fine....one more question is i need to apply your solution to all builder.show(); ?

Comment: glad to help you.. :))

Answer (score 0):

Copy the whole CheckUpdates class inside MainActivity class and use MainActivity.this instead of context in CheckUpdates class at everywhere.